# Can't put process into background using "&"

Tags: command-line

When I type    xlogo &    into the shell prompt, it doesn't return me to the terminal. It keeps me on the xlogo window.

How do I fix this problem so that typing in "&" will return me to the terminal window immediately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think what you're trying to do is possible (without extensive and very hard work).

The `&` has no relation to the X server. It's simply a meaningful character to `bash` that says the following:

> Run command A and command B at the same time. If there's no command B, return the user to the shell.

It has nothing to do with switching the active window in X, running other commands, etc. It has one use only: Running two commands at the same time.

---

With that in mind, it might be possible to write a script that would run a specified command, switch the active window back to the terminal, and then wait for your next command. However, that's out of the scope of this question as we're now getting into scripting.

Comment: I believe your answer has helped me clear out my problem. I was trying to do an exercise from the book "The Linux Command Line by William E. Shotts, Jr." and in it there was an exercise which talked about controlling processes.

Typing in xlogo meant that I had to return to the terminal and Ctrl+C to terminate the process in order to bring back the shell prompt; while typing in xlogo & meant that the shell prompt would return without having to close down the xlogo program. Many thanks!

Comment: The "&" is used for several different things, but in this case, I think he's talking about a trailing "&" used to background the process, not the "and" operator.

Comment: @CharlesBoling That was certainly what I was trying to accomplish. Thanks for clearing it up.